# How to display numbers in scientific notation in ASCII tables?

Tags: r, xtable, stargazer

I am trying to display extremely small numbers (<1E-12) in an ASCII table. (Believe me, I can't find any alternative.)  So far I've tried stargazer and xtable.  Neither of them seems to work.  I can display the numbers in scientific notation with xtable in HTML, but not ASCII.  Stargazer seems not have the option to display numbers in scientific notation.  Below is an example:

```
library(stargazer)
example <- data.frame(parameter = letters, value = runif(26, min = 1E-14, max = 5E-14))
stargazer(example, summary = F, type = "text", digits = NA)
```

All the values are truncated as 0 even if I set the digits option as NA, which is supposed to keep everything.  Any help is really appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You could force it by converting them to strings beforehand...not beautiful, but it'd work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the value to character. I've done this using the `format` function, since that makes it easy to control the number of significant figures. I've also used the `dplyr` package to do the reformatting on the fly:

```
library(dplyr)

stargazer(example %>% mutate(value = format(value, scientific = TRUE, digits = 4)), 
          summary = FALSE, type = "text")
```

> ```
> ======================
>    parameter   value  
> ----------------------
> 1      a     4.456e-14
> 2      b     2.773e-14
> ...
> 25     y     2.982e-14
> 26     z     1.771e-14
> ----------------------
> ```

You could also avoid `dplyr` like this:

```
example$value = format(example$value, scientific = TRUE, digits = 4)

stargazer(example, summary = FALSE, type = "text")
```

Answer (score 2):

Appears you are willing to accept output as character (at least if I'm interpreting your use of "ASCII" correctly). Could also use `sprintf` which accept Fortran-like specifications:

```
> formatC(2e-14, digits=16, format="f")
[1] "0.0000000000000200"
> print( formatC(2e-14, digits=16, format="f") , quote=FALSE)
[1] 0.0000000000000200
> cat( formatC(2e-14, digits=16, format="f") )
0.0000000000000200
```

For scientific notation:

```
> cat( formatC(2e-14, digits=4, format="e") )
2.0000e-14
```

Comment: Thanks 42-.  I'd prefer to have the numbers in scientific notations.